# run another application when there is a URL with a question mark and is equal to react nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-location

I have 2 react build applications, I want to run one of them only when the URL coincides with www.example.com/inventory/?id=...
my config nginx

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl default_server;

index index.html;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com.key;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    root /var/www/example.com/;

location / {
    root /var/www/example.com/public/admin;     
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fmp.sock;
    }
}

    location /inventory/?id= {
    root /var/www/example.com/public/inventory;     
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

I get a 404 nginx error, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is not part to the [normalized URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) used to match a `location` or `rewrite` statement.

Your location block can match all URIs that begin with `/inventory/` but you will need to use an `if` block to reject any requests without a matching argument. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

For example:

```
location /inventory/ {
    if ($arg_id = "") { return 404; }

    root /var/www/example.com/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Note that the path to the file is formed by concatenating the value of the `root` directive with the URI, so unless you mean to include two `inventory` directories in the path, it should not appear in the `root` statement as well. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Comment: at the moment he doesn’t work off the second location and gives me 404 error and
the problem is that on my front end I have a route with inventory/:id , but without a question mark and ID line, will it work the route correctly?